# JMeter - Constant throughput timer per Thread provokes Error in Spring application with lower but not for high throughput

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jmeter, netflix-zuul

I am currently using the Ultimate Thread Group Plugin to create a distribution of 30 Threads for local tests against a Spring Application (spring boot, zuul,...)running on my Mac Book Pro (if that matters).

When I set a per thread throughput timer in the thread group to 2000 per Minute everything works fine. However when I lower it to about 400 per Minute I start to see the following exception:

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Can't assign requested address (Address not available)
```

So what I now would like to know is:

- What does change in the behavior of JMeter that causes the error
- Is there something I can do that error from happening

If you need more information, drop a comment and I will update as good as I can.

Comment: Throughput timer can cause only delay, so this isn't the issue, the issue is the bottleneck you found on sending 400 per Minute requests on specific server

Comment: @user7294900 I thought the same - but how can a bottleneck disappear once I increase the throughput? That's what I do not get. Especially as I assume that the Throughput Timer does regulate throughput until it reaches the max requests processed by the server and then just does nothing until the server can again handle more than the rpm restriction in the Throughput Timer.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. It was client side problem, when maximum concurrent throughput was reached. The best solution I found was [this](https://planet.jboss.org/post/concurrent_high_throughput_performance_testing_with_jmeter). Hope it helps you as well.